# How to Get Mac Desktop size

Tags: objective-c, macos, size, desktop

How do I discover the size of the Desktop (or screen size) of the Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the screen size use [`-[NSScreen frame]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-CJBBEFJG) on an instance received through e.g. [`+[NSScreen mainScreen]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-mainScreen) or [`-[NSWindow screen]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-screen).
To get the visible part without the dock and menu bar, use [`-[NSScreen visibleFrame]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-visibleFrame).

Keep in mind that the full desktop can stretch over multiple screens.

Comment: what if my dock is hidden, and i still want to know the size/location of the Dock?