# (Mac OS X) How to get the sizes/rectangles of the Dock and Menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen, menubar, dock

I can`t find any info about: how to get the dock size/rect? Also How to get the menu bar size/rect? (and all it sub-parties as status menu rect, application menu rect, etc.)

Comment: There are several similar questions on SO regarding this. For example, you can check [How to Get Mac Desktop size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489290/how-to-get-mac-desktop-size).

Comment: user3584460, thx! Your link partially helps me. But I don't found how to receive the pairs of the menu bar, such as status menu rect or application part menu rect. Can you suggest where I could read about it?

Comment: A bit late, but - you can get the the position of status menu as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413784/how-to-get-frame-for-nsstatusitem). As to the application part of the status bar, I do not think this is possible.

Comment: Thx! I will try. Its bad that there are no API for get the application part ((( So I will make sreenshot and will try to detect it by myself.